# svn directory wiped out at random

Tags: svn, directory

I have a problem that is bugging me since a while ago.

Basically, after some time I checkout an svn repository the .svn directories that are both in the root and all subfolders disappear and I cannot run any svn command on that working copy

Are you aware of this issue? Is anybody else having the same problem?

I'm using Mavericks Darwin XXXXXXXXX 13.0.0 Darwin Kernel Version 13.0.0: Thu Sep 19 22:22:27 PDT 2013; root:xnu-2422.1.72~6/RELEASE_X86_64 x86_64

and this is the output of the `svn --version` command

```
svn, version 1.8.5 (r1542147)
   compiled Nov 27 2013, 08:16:39 on x86_64-apple-darwin13.0.0

Copyright (C) 2013 The Apache Software Foundation.
This software consists of contributions made by many people;
see the NOTICE file for more information.
Subversion is open source software, see http://subversion.apache.org/

The following repository access (RA) modules are available:

* ra_svn : Module for accessing a repository using the svn network protocol.
  - with Cyrus SASL authentication
  - handles 'svn' scheme
* ra_local : Module for accessing a repository on local disk.
  - handles 'file' scheme
* ra_serf : Module for accessing a repository via WebDAV protocol using serf.
  - using serf 1.3.2
  - handles 'http' scheme
  - handles 'https' scheme
```

Comment: using an svn 1.8 client there should only be one top level .svn directory.   This is really odd - I've never had anything like this happen on my mac.

Comment: Do you have some kind of compile/build process running against the working copy that's deleting things it shouldn't be?

Comment: No... I find this behavior very weird and I was hoping somebody else noticed the same. I have to check periodically the directory and before doing any modification I have to re-checkout.